# Parallel crawling through large graph with circular references

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, graph-theory

In few words: I want to process large graph with circular references in parallel way. And also I don't have access to full graph, I have to crawl through it. And I want to organize effective queue to do that. I'm interested is there any best practices to do that?

I'm trying to organize infinite data processing flow for such strategy: each thread takes node to process from queue, processes it, after processing - some new nodes for processing might appears - so thread has to put them into queue. But I don't have to process each node more than once. Nodes are immutable entities.

As I understand - I have to use some threadsafe implementation of queue and set (for already visited instances).

**I'm trying to avoid synchronized methods.** So, my implementation of this flow:

1. When thread adding nodes to the queue, it checking each node: if visited-nodes-set contains this node, thread don't add it to
   the queue. But that's not all
2. When thread takes node from the queue - it check if visited-nodes-set
   contains this node. If contains, thread takes another
   node from queue, until get node, which hasn't
   been processed yet. After finding unprocessed node - thread also adding
   it to the visited-nodes-set.

I've tried to use LinkedBlockingQueue and ConcurrentHashMap (as a set). I've used ConcurrentHashMap, because it contains method putIfAbsent(key, value) - which, as I understand, helps atomically: check if map contains key, and if doesn't contain - add it.

Here is implementation of described algorithm:

```
public class ParallelDataQueue {

   private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> dataToProcess = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
   // using map as a set
   private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> processedData = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>( 1000000 );
   private final Object value = new Object();

   public String getNextDataInstance() {
    while ( true ) {
        try {
            String data = this.dataToProcess.take();
            Boolean dataIsAlreadyProcessed = ( this.processedData.putIfAbsent( data, this.value ) != null );
            if ( dataIsAlreadyProcessed ) {
                continue;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    public void addData( Collection<String> data ) {
    for ( String d : data ) {
        if ( !this.processedData.containsKey( d ) ) {
            try {
                this.dataToProcess.put( d );
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
       }
     }

}
```

So my question - does current implementation avoid processing of repeatable nodes. And, maybe there is more elegant solution?

Thanks

**P.S.**

I understand, that such implementation doesn't avoid appearence duplicates of nodes in queue. But for me it is not critical - all I need, is to avoid processing each node more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation does not avoid repeated data instances. Assume that "Thread A" check whether data exist in concurrent map and find out it does not so it will report that data does not exist. But just before executing the if after putIfAbsent line, "Thread A" is suspended. At that time another threat, "Thread B", scheduled to be executed by cpu and check existing of same data element and finds out it does not exist and reports it as absent and it is added to queue. When the Thread A is rescheduled it will continue from the if line and will add it to queue again.

Comment: I understand, that such implementation doesn't avoid appearence duplicates of data in queue. But for me it is not critical - all I need, is to avoid processing each instance of data more than once. Method getNextDataInstance() won't return data, that is already processed. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: It should be ok then. HashMap is one of the fastest way to detect existence of item in a set. You

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html )

also

> When thread adding data to the queue, it checking each instance of data: if set contains instance of this data, thread don't add it to the queue. But that's not all

is not a thread-safe approach, unless the underlying Collection is thread-safe. (which means it's synchronized internally) But then it's pointless to do the check, because it's **already** thread-safe...

Comment: Thnx, but describe, please, how ConcurrentLinkedQueue helps me in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process data in multithreaded manner, you maybe don't need collections at all. Didn't you think about using the Executors framework? :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    while (true) { // provide data ininitely
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            exec.execute(new DataProcessor(UUID.randomUUID(), exec));
        Thread.sleep(10000); // wait a bit, then continue;
    }
}

static class DataProcessor implements Runnable {
    Object data;
    ExecutorService exec;
    public DataProcessor(Object data, ExecutorService exec) {
        this.data = data;
        this.exec = exec;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(data); // process data
        if (new Random().nextInt(100) < 50) // add new data piece for execution if needed
            exec.execute(new DataProcessor(UUID.randomUUID(), exec));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thnx. Yes, of cource I'm using executors, but also I need to avoid processing same data more than once.

Comment: what does 'same data' mean? Is it the case of data1.equals(data2) or data1 == data2 ? Anyway, in both cases, I'm afraid there's a problem with design outside of data processing. Because (of course, IMHO) it's data providers' responsibility to track data. Or, you might to not process piece of data in some specific circumstances...

Comment: For example, if you process social graph with circular relations - you have to avoid processing same persons twice. And this is not problem with application architecture, it's specific of processed data. I want to process graph with circular references in parallel way. And also I don't have access to full graph, I have to crawl through it

Comment: So - point of my question is implementation of data provider :)

Comment: ah, you've changed the problem definition... :) so I can see my answer is pointless now. For graph, I would explore edges instead of vertices, but it's another design, again

Comment: I'm exploring :) hmm.. what do you mean when talking about "edges"? In my problem, each node is an entity (for example - person). I need to collect information about each visited node. In few words - I'd like to do parallel BFS, but I don't have entire graph. I'm crawling through it from node to node

Comment: Edges presumably means the links between the nodes -- links on the web or friendship in a social graph -- rather than the pages or people.